# MySql server not starting on MAMP

Tags: mysql, apache, mamp, httpd.conf

For some reason my MySQL server will not start (running Apache on port 80 and MySql on port 3306). I figured I would just re-install with the latest version of MAMP, but I still get the same error. I tried changing the document root back to the default (htdocs), but this does not change the problem either.

Most importantly, I tried the recommended fix to no avail:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
lsof -i
killall -9 mysqld
```

I do not see any mysqld processes in the Activity Monitor. Rather, I see 7 httpd processes. There was only one when MAMP was working correctly.

p.s. I tried restarting my computer and killing httpd processes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem when I wanted to use a newer version of MAMP with MySql 5.6. Apache would start but MySql would not. After much looking around I did the following out of exasperation.

1. Move MAMP from Applications directory to desktop.
2. Deleted MAMP PRO from Applications directory
3. Deleted MAMP PRO from `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/`
4. Installed MAMP
5. Copied the content from my old mamp `db/mysql/` to the new MAMP `db/mysql56/`.I copied everything except `mysql_upgrade_info`. Don't know if that mattered though.
6. Copied my htdocs from old MAMP to new Installation of MAMP

I then restarted MAMP and things ran. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

So what I had to do for MAMP's MySql server to work was stop my MySQL server under "System Preferences." I have no idea why this used to work fine, but now causes problems. Many of the answers that I've seen online have actually indicated that the MySql server under System Preferences should be running. I'm very unsure why this was suddenly a problem, but I suppose the problem is fixed